# Dependencies between Azure RM linked templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I plan to create two resources in my resource groups: one web app and one service bus. The web app is going to have a connection string to point to the service bus. So, I need to first create the service bus and then add web app with its connection string. For both web app and the service bus, I'm using linked templates. My simplified `azuredeploy.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "myWebAppDeploy",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "dependsOn": [
        "UNKNOWN-DEPENDENCY"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "link/to/webapp.azuredeploy.json",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "name": {
            "value": "myWebApp"
          },
          "connectionStrings": {
            "value": {
              "serviceBusConnectionString": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', 'myServiceBus', 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "myServiceBusDeploy",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "link/to/servicebus.azuredeploy.json",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "name": {
            "value": "myServiceBus"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

No matter what I put in `UNKNOWN-DEPENDENCY` section, I receive the following error:

```
Template deployment returned the following errors:10:02:23 AM - Resource Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules 'myServiceBus/RootManageSharedAccessKey' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "ParentResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'myServiceBus' not found."
  }
}'
```

Looks like it's trying to deploy the web app before the service bus. I have tried the followings, but no luck:

```
"myServiceBus"
"myServiceBusDeploy",
"[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'myServiceBusDeploy')]",
"[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', 'myServiceBus')]"
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'myServiceBusDeploy')]"
"[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', 'myServiceBus')]"
```

I'm out of ideas and don't know how to set up the dependencies between these two linked templates.

**UPDATE:** If I deploy my template again after receiving the error, it will work since the service bus is already deployed in the first deploy. So, I'm pretty sure that the nested/linked templates are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here as Gleb noted is that listKeys is being evaluated immediately (design limitation in ARM which we're trying to fix).

To get around this you can do one of two things:

1) instead of passing the connstr to the template, just pass in the resourceId and perform the listKeys() in the web app deployment.

2) use a deployment output (of the connstr) in the service bus deployment and reference() that deployment output.  This will work, but it also short-circuits /validation on the nested deployment, so #1 is a better overall approach.

HTH

Comment: About approach number 2: a) although we can have a type "securestring" in the output parameters, it's useless. When I use `[reference('myServiceBus').outputs.connstr.value]`, it says the is no property "value" or something like that, in which case I have to use "string". Is it recommended by Microsoft to use string type for something like connstr? b) What do you mean by "it short-circuits validation"?

Comment: securestring\objects are hidden from the output, you cant use those. your options are getting keys exactly where you need them without passing or deleting the deployment that lists keys afterwards @hosjay

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name of the resource you want to depend on **ONLY** if its **UNIQUE**, which, looking at the simplified version, it is. But if you want to be really sure you need to use `resourceId()` function:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'myServiceBusDeploy')]"
```

you can also use `concat()` function, but you need to assemble resourceId string exactly:

```
/subscriptions/guid/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/resource_name
```

Having said that, I dont see why this wouldn't work with your simplified version of the template. Might be the non simplified version has something that might interfere with `dependsOn\resourceId`.

If you are using subscription level deployment you might need to construct something like this:

```
/subscriptions/guid/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/myServiceBusDeploy
```

yeah, like I always tell people here: "nested inline templates are crap, never use them unless you know what you are doing". the error doesnt come from the `dependsOn` property, error comes from the `listKeys()` function. because you are using nested inline deployment, `listkeys()` is being evaluated when the deployment starts, it is not a resource, so it doesnt honour the `dependsOn` property. you need to either move this to a nested template (deployed from url) or use `listkeys()` together with `reference()` function (it implies dependency and waits for the resource to be created).

Comment: I have simplified my own template and tried including the service bus template inline in the template instead of an external file. This is the last version I'm locally trying: https://gist.github.com/hosseinjayride/be3d5e5e354ebdedbf7d5048d5e05d7e and here is the logs: https://gist.github.com/hosseinjayride/dde0f23a15fd30d83a1f30768073b342

Comment: By moving to a nested template, do you mean that `listKeys` function should not be in the template at all? or can I pass this `listKeys` as a parameter to that template? - I have used reference function like this: '[listKeys(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', 'my-service-bus-3874552'), '2017-04-01', 'Full'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString] and still it gives me an error: `The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location` am I using it wrong?

Comment: not sure about reference with `listkeys()`, tbh. I expect it to work, but never tried that. actually, looking at my other templates, i think `listkeys()` should wait for the resource, if its defined in the same template. so in your case you need to move listkeys inside the template and template has to be not inline